# Single Sugar ORM model class won't save members?

Tags: android, sugarorm

I've used Sugar ORM for various projects successfully in the past, and have come across a very unusual problem.

When saving an array of "BoostTest"s, none of them persist to the database. This can be seen [here](https://puu.sh/q8nCH.png).

I'm doing a database drop and recreate before running the batch insert. It works for [many other model classes](http://puu.sh/q8nV7.png) in the same project.

The code for the BoostTest.java file is identical to the other models, just constructors, getters, and setters.

I've tried renaming the class, increasing Sugar ORM DB version, but I'm all out of ideas. Additionally, saving a record via the `BoostTest.save(new BoostTest(1,1,1,1));` syntax also does not work.

BoostTest.java:

```
package uk.co.jakelee.cityflow.model;

import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class BoostTest extends SugarRecord{
    private int boostId;
    private int level;
    private int owned;
    private int used;

    public BoostTest(int boostId, int level, int owned, int used) {
        this.boostId = boostId;
        this.level = level;
        this.owned = owned;
        this.used = used;
    }

    public int getBoostId() {
        return boostId;
    }

    public void setBoostId(int boostId) {
        this.boostId = boostId;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public int getOwned() {
        return owned;
    }

    public void setOwned(int owned) {
        this.owned = owned;
    }

    public int getUsed() {
        return used;
    }

    public void setUsed(int used) {
        this.used = used;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the constructor is required, even if not using it yourself. Sugar ORM will use it internally.

Adding the following to the BoostTest.java class resolved the issue:

```
public BoostTest() {  }
```